# Restoring In app purchase in windows 8 store

Tags: in-app-purchase, restore

Is that possible to Restore the Inapp purchase in Windows Store??

If Yes means help to figure out the solution.

Comment to solve this?? 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My in app purchase (remove ads) was restored with a new installation of the app. Try to reinstall.

Jan